# Partial derivatives in terms of both variables

Tags: partial-derivative

if i have a scalar function as below, i know how to find the partial derivative in terms of x, but can someone gives me some help in understanding how i can take the partial derivative in terms of both variables? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

f(x, y) = sin(xy)

Comment: What do you mean by the "partial derivative in terms of both variables"? Do you know how to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?

Comment: charlotte below has answered my question thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \cos(xy)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}xy\right) = y\cos(xy)$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \cos(xy)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}xy\right) = x\cos(xy)$$

Comment: Hi @AVERAGE, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.